# How can I restrict Hierarchical Select to specific terms?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have the below vocabulary in Drupal 7

> tags
>   -location
>   --uk
>   ---londin
>   ---manchester
>   ---liverpol
>   --france
>   ---paris
>   --germany
>   ---kolhn
>   ---munich
>   -skills
>   --sport
>   ---football
>   ---pingpong
>   ---tenis

I want have a hierarchical select that only uses my selected term and subterms of it.  For example - if I want location, the user only has first level sub term of location in the list, and in level 2 have the subterms of location.

Is there any way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a bug in the HS module that has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a bug in hierarcical select module,and with spend some our about it finally found the solution. 
correct patch is here 
 [this issue in drupal](http://drupal.org/node/263365#comment-6107218)

it's is worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

You should create separate vocabularies. That's the clean & easy solution.
Note that you can move terms from one vocabulary to another so migrating it is not even *that* big an obstacle.

If you really want all terms to be in one big, semantically incorrect vocabulary, then you can. But you'll have to write your own HS API implementation (see the `API.txt` file in the Hierarchical Select module). Start from the `hs_taxonomy` implementation in D7, look at the `hs_content_taxonomy` implementation for D6 to see how it was done there (that implementation *did* support what you need).

Comment: tnx for you reply but, my politic is impelement all in one big vocabulary, i see the api.txt but not found my solution ,can u tell me exactly how do it?

Comment: wim leers you as hs developer tell me about how i can do it witout seprate vocabularies,?

Comment: I told you how you can do it. You'll have to do some programming, but you *can* do it. You cannot reasonably expect every open source project maintainer to just implement everything you need for you.

Comment: tnx for you reply, finally i wrote a module to handle this work with more feature, a cck widget handler. tnx wim.